# Torchviz subtraction node with one input

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

Ive used torchviz to visualize a pytorch graph. One of the nodes have one line in and one line out. Node text "subbackward0 .... alpha 1". Am i rigtht to assume it does nothing?

I did not expect only one line into a sub-box, i expected minimum 2.

Node:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Am i rigtht to assume it does nothing? No, probably there is some other input also to the subtraction node, which isnt being backpropagated thru, like a constant value.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).